# Callback for when an AnimatedFoo widget has finished animating

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I was wondering if there is a way to know once an *AnimatedFoo* widget has completed the animation? I'm currently using `AnimatedSize` and am trying to find a way to call a function once it has completed. I initially also created an `AnimatedController` but it doesn't look like it's accepting any controllers.

```dart
AnimatedSize(
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  curve: Curves.bounceOut,
  child: Container(...),
),
```

Comment: see [onEnd](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget/onEnd.html) - most classes that extend `ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget` have this parameter (note that `AnimatedSize` is not among them)

Comment: Had to use `AnimatedContainer` instead of `AnimatedSize` since it didn't have `onEnd` for some reason. Animation is slightly different but that's probably due to the way I  structured my widgets.

Comment: It did not have it since `AnimatedSize` does not extend `ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget`